# Publish/Version history for forms in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, changelog

Is there any way to determine which user and when that last changed or published a form in Dynamics CRM 2011?

I've looked everywhere that I can think of, from the form itself to auditing, customizations in the default solution, system settings and I can't find anything anywhere.

If it isn't turned on by default, how do I turn on auditing on the framework itself instead of the content so we can know next time something strange happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in log or audit for the customization changes.

You can try to build your own with plugins attached to the `Publish` and `PublishAll` messages

Comment: Argh.. okay, I guess we'll just have to interrogate everyone with admin rights. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: This is the best way going forward but if you wanted to do a bit of blame-storming then you can see when a form was last published and by looking at the user login history narrow it down